# Twitter API Streaming by Locatons

Tags: python, api, twitter, geolocation, streaming

I'm using a Python's Twitter API implementation, TwitterAPI.

I'm trying get tweets from a specific city (São Paulo), in the Twitter Advanced Search(https://twitter.com/search-advanced) website is easy, but when I try to do it using streaming, never returns any tweet. (I know search-advanced is complete different from twitter streaming API)

[image]

Like follow the documentation I get the southwest coordinate first, and northeast after.
https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#locations

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pprint from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(depth=6)

api = TwitterAPI(CONSUMER_KEY,
                 CONSUMER_SECRET,
                 ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
                 ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

r = api.request('statuses/filter', {'locations':'-23.984524,-46.885064,-23.393466,-46.479943'})

for item in r:
    pp.pprint(item)
```

But I never got any tweet, what I'am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the latitudes and longitudes reversed. Try:

```
r = api.request('statuses/filter', {'locations':'-46.885064,-23.984524,-46.479943,-23.393466'})
```

The `locations` parameter takes longitude/latitude pairs.

Comment: I get results when I run your code with the correction in my answer above. Can you explain the problem you are experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

Does using locations as a list of float values help?

```
{'locations':[-46.885064,-23.984524,-46.479943,-23.393466]}
```